# Ionic statubar color not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm trying to change the font color to white in the statusbar for iOS, without any success.

I have set it like this in app.js:

```
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // StatusBar.styleDefault();
  StatusBar.style(1);
}
```

But it does not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These is no such function `style()` available on `StatusBar` object. But these are available on ngCordova version of plugin : `$cordovaStatusbar.style(1);` , here is [link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/statusbar/)  to ngCordova wrapper of this plugin. Plus still if you do not want to use this wrapper then you need to add `<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />` in `config.xml`. Available values are default, lightcontent, blacktranslucent, blackopaque.

Comment: I just tried installing the plugin and using $cordovaStatusbar and just changing the config.xml. Both with no avail...

Comment: `$cordovaStatusbar.style(1);` does not work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

I was testing on the Ionic App, where the status bar pluig does not work. using:

```
$cordovaStatusbar.style(1);
```

Solved my "issue"